# get rid of arrays into an array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I came up with this ugly verbose array (and I have to use it):

```
$puppy_mother_father_arr = array(
    array('46' => array('30','29')),
    array('17' => array('30','29')),
    array('16' => array('24','29'))
);
```

How do I simplify it to something like this :

```
$puppy_mother_father_arr = array(
    '46' => array('30','29'),
    '17' => array('30','29'),
    '16' => array('24','29')
);
```

I've been stuck a day in here. thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$tmp = array();
foreach ($puppy_mother_father_arr as $parent) {
  foreach($parent as $key => $nodes) {
    $tmp[$key] = $nodes;
  }
}
$puppy_mother_father_arr = $tmp;
```

Would this work?

Comment: Wow!!!! that's working :) your genius. tank U so much :) you are a life saver @AlexanderKuzmin

Answer (score 0):

## [See the result online](http://codepad.org/WSgT2luf)

```
<?php
$puppy_mother_father_arr = array( array('46' => array('30','29')),array('17' => array('30','29')),array('16' => array(24,'29')) );


$list = array();
foreach  ($puppy_mother_father_arr as $info)
{
    foreach ($info as $key => $value)
    {
        $list[$key] = $value;
        break;
    }
}
var_export($list);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$newarray = array();
foreach ($puppy_mother_father_arr as $array) {
   foreach ($array as $puppy => $parents) {
       $newarray[$puppy] = $parents;
   }
}
$puppy_mother_father_arr = $newarray;
```

Comment: tank u so much @Marina. brilliant idea

Answer (score 0):

[`key`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.key.php) and [`current`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.current.php) could be useful if each array has only one interested key and value:

```
$result = array();
foreach($puppy_mother_father_arr as $arr) {
    $result[key($arr)] = current($arr);
}
var_dump($result);
```